# How to use a module in verilog as in build operator like OR, AND, XOR etc. function?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I wanted to module GR as the operator. how can I?

```
 module GR(ou,a,b);
    input [7:0] a,b;
    input reset;
    output ou;
    wire o1,o2,o3,o4;
    assign ou=o1 || o2 || o3 || o4;
    TBC call1(o1,a[1],b[1]);
    TBC call2(o2,a[3],b[3]);
    TBC call3(o3,a[5],b[5]);
    TBC call4(o4,a[7],b[7]);
    endmodule
**************************************************************************      
    module TBC(o,a,b);
    input a,b;
    output o;
    assign o=a && (~b);
    endmodule
```

---

```
module five(outt,ack,reset,a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,clka);
input [7:0] a1,b1,c1,d1,e1;
input clka,reset;
output reg [7:0] outt;
output reg ack;

always @(negedge clka) begin
                     if(GR(a1[1],b1[2])) begin
                     b1[2]<=a1[1];a1[1]<=b1[2];
                     end

end
endmodule
```

What correction should I needed?

Edit: As suggested below comment , i make function as below *

```
function GR;
input [7:0] a,b;
wire o1,o2,o3,o4;
begin 
 GR=o1 || o2 || o3 || o4;
 o1=a[1]&&(~b[1]);
 o2=a[3]&&(~b[3]);
 o3=a[5]&&(~b[5]);
 o4=a[7]&&(~b[7]);
end 
endfunction
```

But its giving error : 
Syntax error near "wire"

Comment: It sounds like you want to write GR as a function, not a module. Does Verilog support functions like VHDL does?

Comment: yes it support function. I tried to use function but stuck again as i call TBC module inside GR.

Comment: Well, functions can call other functions...

Comment: HDL is a hardware description language, not a procedural language. You can't "call" a module. You instantiate a module which adds a chunk of hardware that needs to be wired up.

Comment: Until you get your head around the concepts of HDL, stay away from functions. What you are trying to do (I presume anyway) is check the current output value of the GR function (BTW, please give it a sensible name, who knows what GR means), and then do something depending on its value. So you instantiate your GR module like you have the TBC one (again please give it a proper name!) and connect its output to a wire. Then you check the state of that wire.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a HDL, i.e. you are describing hardware. You don't "call" bits of hardware like you would call a function in C or Java or whatever. This is not a procedural language. Any hardware that you require in your design must be described and instantiated at compile time. It will always exist in your design (the hardware doesn't magically appear and disappear when your design is running).

You require a structure something like this:

```
module something(
    ...
);

wire outputOfInstanceWithSensibleName;

//Lets *instantiate* our module. We aren't "calling" it, we are adding
//the hardware that it describes to our design.
someOtherThing instanceWithSensibleName (
    .a(somethingConnectedToA),
    .b(somethingConnectedToB),
    .o(outputOfInstanceWithSensibleName)
);

//Then we do something depending on what the output of that instance is.
always @ (...) begin
    if (outputOfInstanceWithSensibleName) begin
        //Do something when the output of the instance with a sensible name is high
    end else begin
        //Maybe something else when its output is low.
    end
end

endmodule

module someOtherThing(
    input a,
    input b,
    output o
);

...

endmodule
```

It is important to realise that the always block is describing some action which is always happening. If you are using a clock edge sensitivity, the action will always happen on that clock edge (synchronous logic). If you are not using a clock, the action will always be happening all the time (asynchronous logic).

Notice how we instantiate the hardware separately from the always block. If the action relies on some other hardware to compute a value, that hardware must be instantiated, and the output of it connected up using a wire to our always block. The connection is simply a case of wiring up one end to the output of the hardware instance as shown, and then using the other end in some calculation (e.g. if statement, etc.) or connecting it up to the input of another module.